# Pytest AssertionError even if status code is correct

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, assert

Why do I keep getting `AssertionError` when actually 400 is returned as in line 14 is set?

```
14   assert status_code == 400
15   AssertionError: assert (400, 'Please fulfill all parts!') == 400
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're trying to assert that an `int` is equal to a `tuple`.

specifying the index of `status_code` will solve it.

ie: `assert status_code[0] == 400`